# Excel VBA - Is Workbook Open

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to determine if a workbook is already open by the user or by another user on the network and where the file extension may be .xls, .xlsx or .xlsm

1. The workbook path and name is known but the file extension is not.
2. If the workbook is open on the users pc then activate the workbook.
3. If the workbook is open by another user on the network then display message.
4. If workbook is not open then open it.

I have tried using the function below but this requires the file extension to be known otherwise I get a 53 error code

```
Function IsFileOpen(fileName As String)

Dim fileNum As Integer
Dim errNum As Integer

On Error Resume Next
fileNum = FreeFile()

Open fileName For Input Lock Read As #fileNum
Close fileNum

errNum = Err

On Error GoTo 0

Select Case errNum
    Case 0      'errNum = 0 means no errors, therefore file closed
        IsFileOpen = False
    Case 70     'errNum = 70 means the file is already open
        IsFileOpen = True
    Case Else   'Something else went wrong
        IsFileOpen = True
End Select
```

Comment: Why don't you just add in a select statement for each option of xls, xlsx, or xlsm?

Comment: Would it be possible to clarify, if I don't know the type do you mean to retrieve the file type first? Also not sure how this would distinguish between the file being opened by the user, by another user